# primefaces 6 IE11 dialog is null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am upgrading from 3.4 to PF 6. Suddenly the dialog does not work in IE, although I upgraded to use the PF lib. so I am now testing against the PF demo code. The demo code does not work either.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
<p:commandButton value="Basic" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" />

<p:commandButton value="Modal" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg2').show();" />

<p:commandButton value="Effects" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg3').show();"    /> 
</h:panelGrid>

<p:dialog header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40">
   <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
</p:dialog>

<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100">
<h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
</p:dialog>   

<p:dialog header="Effects" widgetVar="dlg3" showEffect="explode"  hideEffect="bounce" height="100">
<h:outputText value="This dialog has nice effects." />
</p:dialog>
```

In IE11 I get in the console:

```
PF('dlg1').show();" type="button"><span class="ui-butt
Unable to get property 'show' of undefined or null reference
```

I am pretty experiences with JSF but maybe I am missing some upgrade setting here for PrimeFaces?

Comment: So it works in FireFox? and http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml works great in IE11

Comment: ok, so the issue was because of a "member not found" error. Most probably that stopped the init of the PF code. I fixed it by adding a facet with the <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

Comment: Yes, that would have been my second suggestion if it indeed did run on FF/Chrome/...